# After split string from a line with 2 string array returned 1 element, so array is out of bounds when accessing array[1]

Tags: arrays, string, visual-c++, split

I am trying to solve this problem.

```
while (readSiteid->Peek() != -1)
        {
                String^ OneLine = (readSiteid->ReadLine());

                if (OneLine != nullptr)
                {
                    array<String^>^ result = OneLine->Split(' ');                                   
                    String^ first = result[0];
                    String^ second = result[1];
```

This results with array out of bounds after compiling. I tested further with MessageBox::Show(result[1]); and got nothing. If only accessing result[0] (remarking result[1]) there is no problem.

What seems to be wrong why the index is only 1?

Comment: Obviously, `Split()` is returning an array with less than 2 elements in it.  That implies that `ReadLine() is returning a string that does not have any spaces in it.  What does the input that is being read from actually look like?

Comment: string1 string2, there is space in between

Comment: Not according to `Split()`.  And BTW, `WholeLine` should be `OneLine`, and `Split()` does not accept a single `Char`, it expects an **array** of `Char`s, eg: `if (OneLine != nullptr) { array<String^>^ result = OneLine->Split(new Char[]{' '}); ... }`

Comment: yes, that was a typo (WholeLine).  I will try your suggestion, thanks...